# could not save preference file google-apps-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Just installed Google Apps Engine and am getting "could not save" errors.

Specifically if I go in to preferences I get

Could not save into preference file
C:\Usera\myname/Google\google_appengine_launcher.ini:No such file or directory.

So some how I have a weird path, would like to know where and how to change this. I have search but found nothing, I have done a repair reinstall of GAE
Can find nothing in the registry for google_appengine_launcher.ini

I first saw the error when I created my first Application
Called hellowd
Parent Directory: C:\Users\myname\workspace
Runtime 2.7 (PATH has this path)
Port 8080
Admin port 8080

click create

Error: 
Could not save into project file
C:\Users\myname/Google\google_appengine_launcher.ini:No such file or directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to my own question.

I have a small app I have written to backup my stuff to Google Drive, this app would appear to have an error in it that does not stop it from running but does cause it to make a file called
 C:\Usera\myname\Google

Therefore GAE can not create a directory called  C:\Usera\myname/Google nor a file called  C:\Usera\myname/Google\google_appengine_launcher.ini

I deleted the file Google, made a directory called Google and ran the GAE, saved pereferences and all working